# Cannot initialize Map Fragment: Missing license key in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using *HERE Android SDK Premium Edition Evaluation* version. I've copied the `BasicMapActivity` in my application but when i try to initialize `mapFragment` i get the error report in the title. I've double check my credentials reported in my plan. I cannot understand why i receive always this error. Can anyone help me to understand?

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.opti.routingdemoapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="com.opti.routingdemoapp.BasicMapActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
            android:label="HereMapService"
            android:process="global.Here.Map.Service.v2"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
            android:value="lj9AGjf7NkRmVtQcnCy6"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
            android:value="1_QQ9-svVHpi5y9AnzW1uQ"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key"
            android:value="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"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and those are my **credential info**:

```
APP ID 
lj9AGjf7NkRmVtQcnCy6

APP CODE 
1_QQ9-svVHpi5y9AnzW1uQ

NAMESPACE 
com.opti.RoutingDemoApp

LICENSE KEY 
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
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the application package name "com.opti.routingdemoapp.BasicMapActivity" match the one you provided to developer.here.com to generate the permission key ?

The problem is likely the namespace in this AndroidManifest file does not match what you have supplied.

Comment: Also, since you posted your license key in public I highly recommend you ask for a new credentials set.